# Redirect/Return inside the Constructor

Tags: php, laravel, oop, redirect, constructor

Can we use redirection or return inside the constructor code? I believe, it will not throw any error if we return something or use redirect inside constructor, but don't think so it's a right approach.
For example, If I talk about laravel MVC

`public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}`

Here I have initialized the auth middleware, but would it be right I do like this:

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->middleware('auth');
   if (!Auth::check()) {
       Redirect::to('admin')->send();
   }
}
```

or Can I use following statements instead of `Redirect::to('admin')->send();`

```
return redirect('admin');
```

or

```
abort('404');
```

or Is it a bad practice to put such code inside the constructor? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see this is bad practice. For stuff that you want to execute before the controller is initialized (like authorization), you use middleware.

You can create your own middleware if you want to do something like an admin check. For more information check the following [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware)

Comment: Okay, so what if I use this like:

`public function __construct() {
        $this->adminAuthorization();
}`


`public function adminAuthorization() {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            Redirect::to('admin')->send();
        }
    }`
Would this work? @markwalet

Comment: That is still exactly the same.. You execute the same code from the constructor. I really would advise you to use middleware. But, codestyle is always debatable.